# add class width jQuery if div have a number

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement, numbers, addition

I want add class in my div have a number.

```
<div class="stock">15 in stock</div>
```

Width jQuery i want add class "low stock" if >=15

Have you an idea

Comment: Yes, many of us here have an idea. Do you?

Comment: You should be setting this class in your server side code.  Whatever generated that "15 in stock" string, should also set the div class.  You don't need jQuery to do this.

Comment: You could check with jquery if your div contains any value "15" and change class accordingly using .contains() and .removeClass() / .addClass() 
here is the link to the documentation : 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/

Comment: I try this but not work .http://jsfiddle.net/VrPdF/35/

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question, here you go:

**HTML**

```
<div class="stock">15 in stock</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $element = $('.stock');
var stock = parseInt($element.text());
if(!isNaN(stock)){
  $element.addClass('low-stock');
}
```